# ComboBox displays a list of string wrong

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

In XAML, I bound a `ComboBox` to a `List` of strings called `Tags`, which I have in my static class called `Settings`.
Here's XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CSV_To_Tags_App.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:CSV_To_Tags_App"
    Title="Window2" Height="435" Width="566">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="x:Static loc:Settings">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Static loc:Settings.Tags}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

An here's my `Settings` class:

```
public static class Settings
{
    public static List<string> Tags = new List<string>() { "Header1", "Header2", "Header3", "Header4" };
}
```

So, I'd like to get a `combobox` which would display a list of `Tags`.
I'm using `DataTemplate`, because later I'll have to display a bigger list of objects and each of them will have `ComboBox` displayed next to it.

Instead I'm getting this:

[image]

I get four `ComboBoxes` and each of them contains letters of the tags I put in my list. So the first `ComboBox` has letters: `H-e-a-d-d-e-r-1`, the second has `H-e-a-d-d-e-r-2`, and so on.

I'd rather want to get one `ComboBox` containing all four tags.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Static loc:Settings.Tags}"/>`

Comment: A string is enumerable, that is whay you see a line for each character. I deleted my answer in favor of answer from @S.Akbari, just wanted to add this explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a `StackPanel` for this purpose. You just need one `ComboBox` and set it's `ItemsSource`. Like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Static loc:Settings.Tags}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

And if you want to use a `DataTemplate` you can use it like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Static loc:Settings.Tags}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. But, to be honest I don't understand why this works and my code does not. I have a problem with understanding of binding - I have no idea what I should put in Source and what should I put in Path.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an Items Control for this to work properly. Just a combobox is enough inside the StackPanel to work. Check below code :

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="x:Static loc:Settings">
        <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{x:Static loc:Settings.Tags}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```